# Copying content from one file to another, segmentation fault

Tags: c, cs50

I'm trying to copy 50 jpegs, one by one from a large .raw file, however currently I get a segmentation fault error. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

//SOI - 0xFF 0xD8
//EOI - 0xFF 0xD9
//APPn - 0xFF 0xEn    
int main(void)
{
    //FAT - 512 bytes per block
    BYTE block[512];

    //open file containing pictures
    FILE* card_file = fopen("card.raw", "rd");

    FILE* jpeg_file;

    //make sure the file opened without errors
    if (card_file == NULL)
    {
        printf("something went wrong and file could not be opened");
        return 1;
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (fread(&block, sizeof(BYTE), 512, card_file) != 0)
    {
        //jpeg start signature
        if(block[0] == 0xFF && block[1] == 0xD8)
        {
            i++;
            if(jpeg_file != NULL)
                fclose(jpeg_file);

            //create a new jpeg file to copy bytes to
            jpeg_file = fopen((char*)i, "w+");
        }

        //write 512 bytes to a jpeg file
        if(jpeg_file != NULL)
            fwrite(block, sizeof(block), 1, jpeg_file);
    }

    fclose(card_file);
return 0;
}
```

when I run it through GDB, my code gets all the way to if(block[0] == 0xFF && block[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAPq0.jpg) == 0xD8), then it skips the condition and segmentation fault occurs. I don't see what might be causing this.
Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Code updated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cs50.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

/*struct jpg*/
/*{*/
/*    BYTE soi[2] = { 0xFF, 0xD8 };*/
/*    BYTE eoi[2] = { 0xFF, 0xD9 };*/
/*};*/

//SOI - 0xFF 0xD8
//EOI - 0xFF 0xD9
//APPn - 0xFF 0xEn    
int main(void)
{
    //FAT - 512 bytes per block
    BYTE block[512];

    //jpeg name
    char name[6];

    bool is_open = false;

    //JPEG
    //struct jpg image;

    //open file containing pictures
    FILE* card_file = fopen("card.raw", "r");

    FILE* jpeg_file;

    //make sure the file opened without errors
    if (card_file == NULL)
    {
        printf("something went wrong and file could not be opened");
        return 1;
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (fread(block, sizeof(BYTE), 512, card_file) != 0)
    {
        //jpeg start signature
        if ((block[0] == 0xFF) && (block[1] == 0xD8) && (block[2] == 0xFF) && ((block[3] == 0xe1) || (block[3] == 0xe0)))
        {
            //assign jpeg name
            sprintf(name, "%d.jpg", i++);
            if(is_open)
                fclose(jpeg_file);

            //create a new jpeg file to copy bytes to
            jpeg_file = fopen(name, "a+");
            is_open = true;
        }

        //write 512 bytes to a jpeg file
        if(is_open)
            fwrite(block, sizeof(block), 1, jpeg_file);
    }

    fclose(jpeg_file);
    fclose(card_file);
return 0;
}
```

Now it doesn't crash, however only 9 out of 50 jpegs are properly recovered. cs50.h is there just so I have access to bool type. What's a better way to write 50 files? I seem to have a logical flaw with my booleans.

Comment: I don't think `fopen()` supports `rd` mode

Comment: `fopen((char*)i, "w+");` wtf?

Comment: You haven't initialized `jpeg_file`.

Comment: Note that `<stdbool.h>` is included by `"cs50.h"` but is the standard way to gain access to type `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

`fopen((char*)i, "w+");` is completely invalid. You are casting an integer as a pointer, which is going to crash.

You need to format the number as a filename:

```
char path[PATH_MAX];
sprintf(path, "%d", i);
fopen(path, "w+");
```

You are also not initializing `jpeg_file` -- if the condition fails, `jpeg_file` will be a wild pointer, which also crashes. You should initialize `jpeg_file` to `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure how to do this. Still seg faulting though.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? jpeg_file was instantiated, but I can't initialize it right off the bat, because I need to know what content to write. I was able to fix crashing, however only 9 out of 50 files are properly recovered. I'm updating my post with current code, I'd appreciate if you would show me alternate/better ways to accomplish this task. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your `fread` call, you should pass the address of the array. Hence, the statement should be `fread(block, sizeof(BYTE), 512, card_file)`.

**Postscript:**

1. In your code, there is assumption that the size of the input file is an integral multiple of 512, which needn't the case for *JPEG* files. The last `fread` might return a number less than 512 which needs to be handled in your implementation logic. Hence, the number of elements to write should be determined by the return value of `fread`
2. You would need to close the `jpeg_file` pointer after the loop terminates.
3. Last, because you are working with *JPEG*, you may want to handle a case for *EXIF* files with thumbnails. In this case, you would get 2 *SOI* (start of image) markers.

Comment: It's a problem set from a class. Based on the instructions, I think, file is in FAT format and all jpegs start at the beginning of memory blocks. Closing jpeg_file is definitely what I added, thanks, but in this case it didn't really matter, files are automatically closed, at least that's what I read. What do you mean by point 3? Can you give an example please?  ------ I'm still crashing though, after making all the changes. I also noticed that my first 2 hex bytes are 0, am I reading them wrong? I added  printf("%X %X\n", block[0], block[1]); to check the values

Comment: @user1937588 Did you modify the `fread` statement to remove the `&` behind `block`? Do you observe the crash even after this change? Point 3 is related to an **EXIF** file where you will have a thumbnail image embedded along with the main image. Please ignore this comment if you aren't familiar with **JPEG** processing. Could you also share the reference to automatic closure of files please?

Comment: 1) Regarding the files, it's mentioned in the "Programming in C" book, 2nd edition, in the chapter that deals with I/O. The author stated that files are closed automatically by the OS as soon as your program is done running, however he encouraged readers to manually close them either way. 2) I fixed the code, it works as I need it to without crashing and it retrieves all jpegs. I was just wondering about alternate code/more effective solution.

Comment: Also, the way FAT is structured is that, jpegs always start at the beginning of the 512 byte blocks. Here's a screenshot of teacher's explanation:  http://snag.gy/RaUiJ.jpg

Comment: @user1937588 I think your current code is fine. Regarding the file closure, it is always recommended to explicitly close the files before leaving a function/scope to ensure that you don't leave the chance to the system to close it for you. It is a recommended programming practice.